# flutter: App not installed then open in play store Deep linking

Tags: flutter, deep-linking, applinks, flutter-deep-link

I am using deep linking for sharing event with that Id and I want here when my app is not install then redirect on playStore not website.
At this time when I am clinking on link then redirect on website not redirecting on playstore(At this time app is not installed).
menifest file deep linking.

```
<!--deep Linking-->
            <meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="mycwc.org" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
```

### Note: I dont want to use firebase_dynamic_link because in firebase dynamic link showing a note "
Dynamic Links is no longer recommended."
so how to implement it with deep linking